# Impacts of reducing size of a SQL server VM on Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We have SQL server VM.

We were facing following problems with it on 26/09/2013.

-Not able to take its remote control

-Status was running , End point was perfect

-Restarted but doesnt worked

We have changed the VM size from small to medium as similer thread suggested, It worked.

1 ) Can you advise what would be impacts of reducing size of this SQL server VM ?

2 ) How this kind of problem can be handled at monitoring dashboard for VM? i.e. azure can alert/mail when VM is out of reach!! ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure recommends a minimum of medium VM size for most of their SQL Server images (if you happen to be using one of their images).  Depending on the version of SQL server you're using, you may have issues with the low RAM on a small VM as your DB's grow.

As far as monitoring, in the azure portal, under Management Services you can set up alerts for your VM which will email you if any of your conditions are triggered.

Comment: Hi can you please advise on below,  1) What if I reduce the size of VM does that effect my VHD or data? can i take backup of VHD ? can i set up availability set to avoid data lost in such condition?  2) Monitoring system can give us alert if VM is connected and working fine , in my case VM has lost N/W connectivity  ,I was not able to ping it or RDC it. Is that any option to alert User about this issue?

Comment: I just realized that you may have experienced this outage due to scheduled maintanace that Azure was running on VM's just recently.  If that was the case, an availability set helps in those situations as well as some others.  Your VHD is in a storage account, where you can access.  You can also use azure backup.